# Is it possible to use EPPlus in dotnet core app running in a windows docker container?

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, gdi+, epplus

I have a dotnet core 2.1 web api that has an action that generates a .xlsx spreadsheet. It creates a FileStreamResult that the browser can then handle. The code to generate the spreadsheet is like so:

```
using (var excelFile = new ExcelPackage())
using (var worksheet = excelFile.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet 1"))
{
    ...
    //insert data into worksheet

    return new FileStreamResult(new MemoryStream(excelFile.GetAsByteArray()), "application/octet-stream") { FileDownloadName = "Report.xlsx" };
}
```

Hosting this in IIS works fine and will generate the spreadsheet.
When I host the app in a windows docker container specifically the image: `microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime-nanoserver-sac2016` I get the following exception when trying to generate the report:

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Gdip'
>   threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load
>   DLL 'gdiplus.dll'

After a bit of research I realise gdiplus is not present in the nanoserver image.

Is it possible to use EPPlus to create a spreadsheet on a dotnet core app hosted in the nanoserver image? Or will I have to use another library to generate the xlsx? I'd like to use EPPlus if possible. I cannot use a linux container (for now anyway unfortunately)

Comment: Great question. Viqas would be proud.

Comment: Have you considered building on top of Server Core instead of Nano Server?

Comment: I have considered this, but this is currently a relatively small feature and seems overkill to build on server core. From what I understand nano server is ideal for hosting dotnet core from a speed and security point of view. If I can't avoid then I may have to go down that route. I was hoping there was another way I had missed

Comment: Try using [Spire Xls](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/excel-for-net-introduce.html) instead. I've found this to be a great tool.

Comment: can you confirm is doesn't use gdi plus?

Comment: looks like it'll have the same issue, and also does not support .net core

Comment: Ahhhh yes you're right, my bad. I actually spent a day trying to get it to work in .net core!

Comment: Yes, Nano server is ideal because of the smaller image size and reduced security footprint. But you can still try out Server Core, it will likely meet your needs and be good enough, without having to resort to wonky hacks like modifying EPPlus source code. For a longer term solution, you could try opening an issue with EPPlus to see if they're willing to create a workaround for the GDI+ dependency.

Comment: I'll create an issue with EPPlus as I'm sure this will become more of a problem as people move towards containers. I'll give the Server Core a go too as this is still an issue for me, thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it will work, but try commenting out any of the methods from the library that uses `System.Drawing.Common`, such as `AutoFitColumns()`. That is what was causing it to break on my linux container.

Comment: i'll see if I can do that, by its nature it is a short term solution because in the future I may need to use `System.Drawing.Common` and then I'll be in this situation again. It may provide the remedy in the short term however.

Comment: This did work for me, and until I require further features, this will work fine. there is always the back up of building the docker image on server core. but glad I don't have to do that for now!

Answer (score 1):

You can build you own ubtuntu/dotnetcore image! I just did it myself for this very problem.

From a command line:

```
docker pull ubuntu

docker run -t -t ubuntu:latest /bin/bash -> to open a container shell ->

    apt-get update

    apt-get install wget    

    wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb

    dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb

    apt-get install apt-transport-https

    apt-get update

    apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.2
```

Install the special libraries we need to resolve the System.Drawing/EPPlus problem here:

```
    apt-get install libgdiplus

    cd /usr/lib

    ln -s libgdiplus.so gdiplus.dll

    apt-get install libc6-dev libx11-dev

    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Find the container process id in a **second** command line window and commit the image:

```
docker ps 


    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
    4975113bb79        ubuntu:latest       "/bin/bash"         9 minutes ago       Up 9 minutes                            infallible_poincare

docker commit d497 custom/imagename:dotnetcore-2.2-custom

docker ps kill d497

docker image rm ubuntu
```

Now you have a custom ubuntu image(the same image that dotnetcore uses) with the sdk loaded and the libraries you need to stop the errors.

The image could probably be trimmed down quite a bit, be warned, this was my first successful attempt at solving this problem where other methods I found online did not succeed due to corporate firewall restrictions and such.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i was specifically looking for a solution for windows containers. When I'm able to use linux containers I will definitely look to your solution!